# SMTP, disappearing E-Mail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have an Ubuntu Linux system which hosts the domain zbmc.eu registered at gandi.net.  The zone file
there is configured to point at this system and the MX record is set up too:-

```
chris@cheddar$ host zbmc.eu
zbmc.eu has address 84.92.49.234
zbmc.eu mail is handled by 10 zbmc.eu.
chris@cheddar$
```

I have several E-Mail addresses (e.g. chris@isbd.co.uk, chris@isbd.net, cl@isbd.net) which are configured on my main hosting provider TsoHost where isbd.co.uk and isbd.net are hosted.  E-Mail from all these addresses is sent to chris@zbmc.eu, this is done
by forwarding from the TsoHost servers.  This has been working well for several years and is still working fine.  I.e. mail sent
to chris@isbd.co.uk gets forwarded by the TsoHost mail servers to chris@zbmc.eu and arrives on my Ubuntu linux machine (which runs
a Postfix mail server).

So, the TsoHost mail servers can send E-Mail successfully to chris@zbmc.eu.

The problem is that I now want to send E-Mail from elsewhere to chris@zbmc.eu and this doesn't work at all. I have
tried sending from PlusNet webmail, from an independent Linux box and from Gandi, none of them work, the mail just
disappears, no errors, no bounce, nothing.

The problem is the same whether sending E-Mail from an MUA or when sending direct from a program (like cron sending an
error message, the thing that raised this whole can of worms).  I can monitor the postfix installation on my BeagleBone
black sending an E-Mail to chris@zbmc.eu (using the TsoHost mail servers at mail3.gridhost.co.uk) and it looks just the same as
sending to chris@isbd.net, but the chris@zbmc.eu disappears.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong. Also what's the normal way to diagnose this sort of problem?

I have full access to some of the systems which attempt to send messages to chris@zbmc.eu and full access to the final destination system but obviously not to the 'smarthost' servers that I'm using in the middle.

Comment: Check your logs on the destination server.

Comment: I think the MX server can't be the zone. It can have the same IP address, but not the same name

Comment: That's a possibility.  I suspect that something really stupid is the reason for this.  I'll go and see if I can change it.

Comment: I agree it must be DNS.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually very simple.  I have a firewall on my server that blocks incoming SMTP traffic from everywhere except the TsoHost servers.  Thus E-Mail from anywhere except the specifically allowed TsoHost servers is blocked.

I had just forgotten about this firewall, a reply on another mailing list in response led me to the answer.

I feel rather silly now, everything is working perfectly and exactly as it should!  :-)

Comment: Silly, bah.  You solved the problem.  That's what matters.